The establishment of Out-of-Time-Ordered Correlators (OTOCs) from Lyapunov Exponents (LEs)?
the OTOC in quantum system is
$$F(t) = \langle \hat{W}^\dagger(t) \hat{V}^\dagger(0) \hat{W}(t) \hat{V}(0) \rangle_{\beta}
$$
the Lyapunov exponent is
$$\lambda = \lim_{{t \to \infty}} \lim_{{d(0) \to 0}} \left( \frac{1}{t} \ln \left[ \frac{d(t)}{d(0)} \right] \right)
$$
where $$d(t) = \sqrt{\Delta x(t)^2 + \Delta p(t)^2}
$$
I don't know how to establish of Out-of-Time-Ordered Correlators (OTOCs) from Lyapunov Exponents (LEs)?
In other words, how did they come up with this quantity?
